# J48 decision tree

Tags: data-mining, decision-tree

I've been searching the web on how to generate J48 decision trees but so far after almost a couple days I haven't found any result about how to generate a J48 decision without Weka, I mean manually by hand. The reason why I wanna do this is because I need to evaluate my data in an assignment.

I would appreciate any information about the j48 algorithm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `J48` classifier implements the [C4.5 algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C4.5_algorithm). You should be able to use either a description of that or, if you need to be exactly like what Weka does, you can step through the code itself.

Comment: my problem is that I don't know how to do this manually, I can do this in many software like weka but I haven't found even a single tutorial on how to draw a decision three based on this algorithm.

Comment: There's pseudocode on the Wikipedia page. You can find a lot more information on this on the web, e.g. in [these slides](http://www.comp.lancs.ac.uk/~kc/Lecturing/csc355/DecisionTrees_given.pdf).

Comment: Thank you Lars, those slides were really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

you can use weka as well for developing a simple code, what you have to do, download the jar file of weka, and study the API of weka which is provided by weka as well. and develop your own program to use the algorithm and implement it on your data